# Codeigniter Active Record HAVING clause with aggregate function MAX

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to use an aggregate function with the HAVING clause in a SQL query, using Codeigniter's Active Record.

```
function get_last_each()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $q = $this->db->from('points')->group_by('nodeid')->having('max(timestamp)', NULL)->get();

    return $q->result_array();
}
```

It gives me a database error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax ...
SELECT * FROM (`points`) GROUP BY `nodeid` HAVING max(timestamp) =
```

If I use `max(timestamp)` in the second argument, the generated query ends like `= max(timestamp)`. Also used the third parameter to disallow query escaping, without success.

The query runs fine on mysql client:

```
mysql> select nodeid, timestamp from points group by nodeid having max(timestamp);
+-----------+---------------+
| nodeid    | timestamp     |
+-----------+---------------+
| 10EF7F    | 1400497730790 |
| ADCFB2    | 1400501296786 |
...
```

How can I achieve this with Codeigniter using having function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your having clause does not make sense, having is used when you are doing some comarison like =, > etc. The active record library like wise looking for a value to compare as you can see

```
HAVING max(timestamp) =
```

The same query could be re-framed as

```
select nodeid, max(timestamp) from points group by nodeid
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I changed the actual query to your suggestion. The call to Codeigniter was like: $q = $this->db->select('nodeid, max(timestamp)')->from('points')->group_by('nodeid')->get();